# Should I keep database connection open?

Tags: node.js, titan, rexster

When I connect to Rexster graph server with Grex should I keep the database connection open?

```
var grex = require('grex');
var client = grex.createClient();

client.connect({ graph: 'graph'}, function(err, client) {
    if (err) { console.error(err); }

    ...
});
```

I think I should because nodejs is single threaded so there's no chance of different requests trying to use the one connection at the same time.

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded for normal code. For asynchronous code (callbacks or events) JS is multithreaded.

Comment: I think its a single thread that switches between different blocks of code. So if you have some code that waits for a callback , Javascript goes off elsewhere and then returns to the callback when its done waiting for something and finished whatever else it was running. But its never running more than one bit of code at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should. There 's no reason to have the overhead of connecting on every request. There will not be any issue of "mangling", as your code will be run in a single thread anyway.

Furthermore, you could even have a pool of connections waiting to serve your requests in case you have a heavy usage application. Some adapters do it for you automatically, for example, [MongoClient](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html) has a default pool of 5 connections.

Comment: On seconds thoughts, isn't it just the http request bit that's single threaded? async operations like database access are handed off to threads so surely you can have more than one query running at the same time?

Comment: @IanWarburton On Nodejs, the code you write runs on a single thread. All IO operations are sent to "the loop", which is a pool of threads doing stuff in a specific way out of your way. That's why you have callbacks - IO says "ready!", callback fires. You can have lots and lots of queries running at the same time on the IO side and being handled by "the loop", on your code they will all fire their own separate callback one by one.

Comment: ... and if you use a single connection for all the db work won't each thread be using the same transaction?

Comment: 1 thread for say 100000 users doesn't sound very performant. Wouldn't it be better to have ten connections and ten threads running concurrently?

Comment: @IanWarburton Isn't my post talking about connection pooling as a "should do" thing? ;)

Comment: Yes excellent. You also say in your answer that, 'There will not be any issue of "mangling"', if there is only one connection. I don't see how this is the case. If node's single thread sequentially sets up multiple db queries in the loop, how would node or the thread or whatever know if the db thread is currently busy with an existing query? As far as I can see, the connection is just sitting there in memory available to be sent a new query.

Comment: @IanWarburton To get a good understanding on how the event loop works on nodejs, this is a fantastic read: http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/index.html - you'll learn more than you ever wished :)